# How to extract specific text from a string in PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, substring

I am working on a WordPress theme, each post has a custom field with a value of mix elements. Some text, some `iframe` and some links I want to only detect `src` tag and the value of `src` tag

below is the example of one custom field :
[image]

I want to only extract the ***src*** tag, so I can get `src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MxpVA4kURdE"` or `https://www.youtube.com/embed/MxpVA4kURdE`

Comment: Please never post a screenshot of code. Instead past the part related to your issue inside a code block. What did you try? What is the expected result? Can you show us some code?
Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it.
Thank you!

Comment: To add to the above comment, volunteers need to be able to copy-paste code and text into their editors in order to efficiently help. Also, text can be *very* difficult to read, depending on the user's device.  For instance, I often use my phone to reply, edit, and review posts.